# Overclocking a GTX 1050

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, gpu

I am trying to overclock a GTX 1050 on Ubuntu. I've tried the coolbits option but it didn't work, and nvclock is outdated. How do I overclock my GPU without coolbits or nvclock?

SPECS

OS: Ubuntu 1604

CPU: i7 7750

GPU: GTX 1050

Answer (score 1):

Pascal class cards like the [GTX 1050 are voltage locked](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/gtx-1050-overclock.3212438/), so your options are extremely limited without hardware modes, which are beyond my depth.